# How can I save a copy of an element in an arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

At present I have an `ArrayList<Waypoint>` where `Waypoint` is a simple class that is used to represent a position in an x/y-grid. Now I noticed that for one method I am always using the same instane of a `Waypoint` object -- but I keep changing it's values.

So if we have say a `Waypoint WP` which is initialised as `X = 0, Y = 0` and I add that to the `ArrayList`, what exactly is saved? The `WP` element or just a copy that holds it's values? Or, asked differently, if I would now increment the values of `WP` and save it to the `ArrayList` would the elements at position 0 and 1 in the `ArrayList` be exactly the same?

If yes, is there an "easy" way to create and save a copy a `Waypoint` element without having to create a new `instance` every time?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *If yes, is there an "easy" way to create and save a copy a Waypoint element without having to create a new instance every time?* Isn't this a self-contradictory statement?  You want to create a copy without creating a copy?  Or are you just disinclined to use the `new` keyword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java works by references so the `Waypoint` object, if not explicitly cloned, will be the same.

If you keep a reference to it you can easily change its values while having these reflected into the same object contained in the list, just because they both reference to the same instance.

This will show the behavior you need:

```
static class Pair
{
    int x,y;

    public Pair(int x, int y) { this.x = x; this.y = y; }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    java.util.ArrayList<Pair> pairs = new java.util.ArrayList<Pair>();
    Pair p = new Pair(0,0);
    pairs.add(p);
    p.x = 20; p.y = 40;
    System.out.println(pairs.get(0).x+" "+pairs.get(0).y);
}
```

You'll see that output is `"20 40"` as you'd expect.

If you want to generate a new waypoint from the one you are starting from then you should define your own method and duplicate explicitly the object.

Doing

```
list.add(p);
// modify p
list.add(p);
```

would just insert the same element twice, which is not what you are looking for. Instead:

```
 list.add(p);
 Waypoint p2 = p.duplicate();
 list.add(p2);
```

would insert two different objects (assuming that `duplicate` actually instantiates a different object with `new`)

Answer (score 0):

From the info you've shared, the answer is yes. You are adding the same instance to the array twice.

The easiest way for you copy an object is to define a constructor that takes the original as an argument and copies the necessary members.

Answer (score 0):

There is no implicit copying in Java. All objects are manipulated through references, and any changes to an object will affect anyone who holds a reference.

To avoid the confusion of who holds what values, it is good practice to make most objects [immutable](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=29).

As for your question, a "copy" is by definition a new instance, otherwise it wouldn't be a true copy.